# AUTH_USER, Claims, and Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, wif, claims

I am attempting to implement a claims based solution into an application. I have an MVC/Classic ASP application, as well as an STS. After authenticating with the STS, I can see the AUTH_USER server variable from my MVC pages. However, this (as well as AUTH_TYPE, LOGON_USER, etc) are not visible in my Classic ASP pages. I would like to be able to test against a server variable that a user is in fact authenticated on the server. If possible, I could read the claim created by the STS to validate the user with my classic ASP pages (not sure if that's an option)

Basically I need a way for my classic asp pages to know that the user is valid when I am logging in via an STS.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")` in your asp pages?

Comment: Yes I have. I mentioned that this variable isn't present through my asp pages as well :/